# Navigating from children screen to parent's sibling screen in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have few questions about React Navigation. I want to navigate from child screen to parent's sibling component, but I couldn't find a proper way for that. My navigation in the app looks like this:

Stack (Main)

- LoginPage
- Desk (DrawerNavigation)

  - Messages
- MyAccount

Here I want to navigate to MyAccount, from Messages (Desk's child screen). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [@react-navigation/stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator), [@react-navigation/drawer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) to config and [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) to redirect screen:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

const STYLE = {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  width: "100%",
};

function LoginPage() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={STYLE}>
      <Text>LoginPage</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to DrawerNav"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Desk")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Messages() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={STYLE}>
      <Text>Messages</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to MyAccount"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MyAccount")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function MyAccount() {
  return (
    <View style={STYLE}>
      <Text>MyAccount</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Desk = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Messages">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginPage">
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginPage" component={LoginPage} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Desk"
          component={Desk}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="MyAccount" component={MyAccount} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```